# illegal start of type, <identifier> expected, ';' expected errors

Tags: java, android, frameworks

My code:
https://github.com/LightningFastRom/android_frameworks_base/blob/next-20200913/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java

I am trying to set that only if the build type is eng it will show the build number. But there's a lot of errors when compiling:

```
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:106: error: illegal start of type
        if (android.os.Build.TYPE.equals("eng")) {
        ^
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:106: error: <identifier> expected
        if (android.os.Build.TYPE.equals("eng")) {
                                        ^
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:106: error: illegal start of type
        if (android.os.Build.TYPE.equals("eng")) {
                                         ^
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:108: error: ';' expected
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                                ^
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:108: error: ';' expected
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                                                        ^
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:108: error: not a statement
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                                                         ^
error: /home/android/lineage-17.1/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/qs/QSFooterImpl.java:108: error: ';' expected
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                                                            ^
```

Comment: You're not allowed to put a method directly inside another method.

Comment: I've updated the code, please check again.

Comment: Is it still not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its syntax error braces not closed properly

try this:

```
    private final ContentObserver mDeveloperSettingsObserver = new ContentObserver(
            new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper()) {
                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                    if (android.os.Build.TYPE.equals("eng")) {
                        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                        setBuildText();
        
                    }
                }});
```

Comment: You are the closest to my final code, so hats of to you.

Comment: @TipzTeam you don't use some IDE?

Comment: @code_mechanic This is the source code of SystemUI...

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your code, please check this function

```
private final ContentObserver mDeveloperSettingsObserver = new ContentObserver(
                new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper())) {
        if (android.os.Build.TYPE.equals("eng")) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
                super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                setBuildText();
            }
        }
    };

// new Handler(...) { }, is a functional interface and you can only write inside th `onChange` method , curly braces after constructor is class body, you cannot write statements there, so put your checks inside the function. It will compile.
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see issue at lines L104 to L113. You are trying to override method based on an if condition which is not allowed. You need to put condition in method definition itself.

```
private final ContentObserver mDeveloperSettingsObserver = new ContentObserver(
            new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper())) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
        // put if condition here
        if (android.os.Build.TYPE.equals("eng")) {
             setBuildText();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I am not aware of your logic, but I think you should call `super.onChange(selfChange, uri);` method on first line, outside `if`

Comment: It's not "my" logic, it's google's logic. This is the Android framework of SystemUI.